# Subsetting in data.table using dot notation

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I am trying to learn `data.table` but got immediately puzzeld by the proposed subsetting. I am working with one of the cran vignettes (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) with the following sample data:

```
grpsize = ceiling(1e7/26^2) 
DF <- data.frame(
   x=rep(LETTERS,each=26*grpsize),
   y=rep(letters,each=grpsize),
   v=runif(grpsize*26^2),
   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

setDT(DF)
```

What would be the best way to subset this dataset if I want the following conditions fullfilled: `x = "B"`, `y = "c"` and `v > 0`?

The vignette proposed for the first two conditions this:

```
setkey(DF, x, y)    
DF[.("B","c")]
```

I understood that this is actually doing a join.
But how can I add the third condition to this? I am well aware of the fact that I could do the whole thing as I would do it with a normal `data.frame`. But quoting the vignette:

> We can do vector scans in data.table, too. In other words we can use
>   data.table badly.

Comment: Can't you use it in two steps `DF[.("B","c")][v > 0]` or perhaps `DF[DF[.("B","c"), .I[v > 0] ,by = .EACHI]$V1]`

Comment: The linked FAQ doesn't seem to contain that quote.

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, that was the wrong link. I edited  the question.

Comment: Ok, fyi, latest vignettes are available as html on the project site: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: @akrun: After reading the tutorial Frank supposed I think "chaining" (or what we called 2-step) would be the prefered solution. If you want to post that as a solution I will accept it. 
However, after reading the new vignette I am not sure whether subsetting this way makes sense because I could not find it there. Does anybody know why it was supposed in the old vignette?

Comment: @Alex I will leave it as comment as I am not sure either which one is the most efficient.